# Why is my Super Table field returning the ID for existing blocks?

Tags: templating, plugin-supertable

I have a front-end profile form that is using a Super Table field to populate a user's phone number.

If the user has not populated the field before, everything works great. I am able to use `new1` to collect the user's information.

It is when I am trying to display existing data that I am getting the error

> Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a string variable ("92").

I am following [this guide](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable/wiki/Updating-a-Super-Table-field-from-a-front-end-form) to help show existing data.

This is what my template looks like:

```
{% set fieldHandle = 'phoneNumber' %}
{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle(fieldHandle) %}
{% set blocktype = craft.superTable.getSuperTableBlocks(field.id)[0] %}

<input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}]" value="">


<label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>

{% if currentUser.phoneNumber.phoneNumber|length %}
    {% for block in currentUser[fieldHandle] %}
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ block.id }}][type]" value="{{ blocktype }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ block.id }}][enabled]" value="1">

        <input type="text" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ block.id }}][fields][phoneNumber]" value="{{ block.phoneNumber.phoneNumber }}">    
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][new1][type]" value="{{ blocktype }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][new1][enabled]" value="1">

    <input type="text" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][new1][fields][phoneNumber]"
    {%- if currentUser is defined and currentUser.phoneNumber.phoneNumber|length -%}value="{{ currentUser.phoneNumber.phoneNumber }}"{%- endif -%}>
{% endif %}
```

While trying to debug myself, this:

```
{{ currentUser[fieldHandle] }} // 92
```

So this:

```
{% for block in currentUser[fieldHandle] %}
```

...is really saying "for block in 92". So, that is why I am *getting* the error, I'm not sure what the correct syntax is to resolve the error though.

**My super table is set to have a max rows of 1 and static field is selected.**

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key thing here is that its a static Super Table field, which is treated differently to a repeatable one. Instead of looping through each block, there's only one. Fortunately, you have all the required information, as this is in fact the `blocktype` variable.

```
{% set fieldHandle = 'mySuperTableField' %}
{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle(fieldHandle) %}
{% set blocktype = craft.superTable.getSuperTableBlocks(field.id)[0] %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

    {# Start with the top-level Super Table field #}
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}]" value="">

    {# Ensure any existing rows in your Super Table field are saved #}
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ blocktype }}][type]" value="{{ blocktype }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ blocktype }}][enabled]" value="1">

    <input type="text" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ blocktype }}][fields][customField1]" value="Value 1">
    <input type="text" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ blocktype }}][fields][customField2]" value="Value 2">
    <input type="text" name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ blocktype }}][fields][customField3]" value="Value 3">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```